# Where can I make requests about deleting a Question

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-delete

There is a Question which was asked by me and which just *has* to be deleted. Along with other Stack Overflow users, I tried to flag it (twice) but to no avail; and SO won't let me delete it on my own. Eventually, it got closed, but it is still hanging around with hasty and incompetently upvoted answers that are plain wrong and misleading, misinforming Stack Overflow visitors further. And I would't wish answers to any of my question to give wrong information, while all the current 3 answers to it do just that.

Here is the link:

[Does passing an object as a parameter for a method increment its retain counter under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522356/does-passing-an-object-as-a-parameter-for-a-method-increment-its-retain-counter)

So, should I make requests about deleting a Question here or somewhere else?

Comment: Put the link in here, without it we can only guess why your request to delete it via flag was declined.

Comment: The question is this one I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522356/does-passing-an-object-as-a-parameter-for-a-method-increment-its-retain-counter

Comment: @MadScientist Done.

Comment: It seems your problem is mostly with the answers. So why retract the question? And please don't preface your questions with this huge block of irrelevant explanation of why you want to see it gone. Address it here, but keep your questions clean.

Comment: You probably didn't explain in the flag why it should be deleted. Anyway you convinced me, need either 2 more 20K+ members or one moderator.

Comment: Did asking about "Where can I make requests about deleting a Question" really deserve a downvote, was it that useless for meta and SO users to know the answer to it?.. SO disappoints me every single day lately.

Comment: [Downvotes are different on meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) By the way, the question has now been deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that question deletions figure into the [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).  We also generally do not like to delete duplicates because people use different search terms to search for the same thing.

In this case, the people who were 'helpfully' deleting the question may not have been so helpful after all -- mostly because good answers were lost and valuable search terms were discarded.

I've merged the question to retain the answers and the question still exists for purposes of searching. If you really don't want the question under your name, flag it and we will disassociate it from your account.

Comment: I don't care about bans. I just didn't want to be involved in spreading of misinformation. And no good answers were lost, the question didn't have any of such. But Ok, how do I flag it in that way?

Comment: George, are you 100% sure the answers are technically good and correct? I have no knowledge of the language used there so I took the OP word the answers were outright wrong. Users are human: they might have upvoted answers out of a whim, not because they are actually correct.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd All the 3 answers were stating that an object passed to a method _is not_ retained under ARC, while in this [official mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2011/Nov/msg00005.html) which was discovered later, it is firmly stated that "these two assumptions force the compiler to retain passed in objects more often than not" which goes in _direct_ contradiction with those 3 answers.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It doesn't matter much what I think, the *community* upvoted the answers and saw value in them.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Flagged it with "I don't want the question under my name, please disassociate it from my account."

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ..so according to the mailing list I mentioned, 0% of those answers were technically good or correct.

Comment: @DesmondHume - There's no need to dissociate this question from your account, as it is a perfectly good question to ask. The answers are not misleading at all. The accepted answer in the now merged question quotes from the appropriate source, but Stephen has a good point in response to your query about that mailing list post in that this could be considered to be an implementation detail and you're probably safer relying on GCD anyways. Neither his nor BJ's answers are actively harmful, in that they both encourage you to err on the conservative side.

Comment: @BradLarson My question was not about concurrency programming or GCD or what BJ thinks about GCD, it was about does or does not a passed object get retained? I didn't care was it a part of ARC philosophy or implementation detail, all I cared was about facts and an answer "yes" or "no", optimally with some support from credible sources. Therefore every single answer, all 3 of them, that controverted the facts coming from the official source (the mailing list) was absolutely, 180 degree misleading.

Comment: @DesmondHume - "As I see it, knowing the answer might have some important implications for multithreading programming..." You specifically talked about implications around concurrency, and their answers addressed that. Why are you so bothered by this? Again, their answers are not at all misleading, in that they state what applies in manual reference counting and the published documentation, and even if ARC does retain these arguments at worst an incorrect answer would cause you to simply be more cautious around threads, which is never a bad practice.